# in salesforce Dynamic action filters not working for community

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

Dynamic action filters only work for internal users (admin) but not community view.

Scenario - I am using the dynamic action filters for the conditional rendering of button.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Actions are not yet available in Experience Cloud, unfortunately.

There is an idea on the [IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbhOUAR/enable-dynamic-forms-dynamic-actions-for-the-communities-interface) to add it.